# how can i print instagram reply message in python using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, bots, instagram

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import schedule

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/badernm/Desktop/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/password/reset/')
usrname_bar = browser.find_element_by_name('cppEmailOrUsername')
username = '17pii_'
usrname_bar.send_keys(username + Keys.ENTER
```

i need to print the result that is ("thanks! check your email for reset link ")
or ("no account with this email")

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-created your program and added 4 extra lines that grab that text from the pop-up you want. Then it prints the text to your terminal. I also took out the 'schedule' library because I saw that you weren't using it in your code, but you can add it back in if you're just showing us a snippet of your program.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/badernm/Desktop/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/password/reset/')
usrname_bar = browser.find_element_by_name('cppEmailOrUsername')
username = '17pii_'
usrname_bar.send_keys(username + Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(1)  # Wait for pop-up message
result = browser.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div/div/div/div/p")  # Path to pop-up
print(result.text)  # Get pop-up text
browser.quit() # Quit browser process
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element by class name. It will look something like this:

```
reply = browser.find_element_by_class_name("CgFia")
print(reply.text)
```

Comment: it didn't work ); , can i get your twitter to send you the result ?

Comment: I don't use twitter. What is the className of  the element you want to check the text of?
Also, not related to the actual problem ,but don't post your computer username (or any other personal info) on public forums.

Comment: alright thanks , the class name i want to print is ("gxNyb") , but when i put it and run the code i get too many errors .

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help further than this. If you can somehow get selenium to access the element then you can use `element.text` to get the text.